Measuring BLDC Motor Speed with Angle Feedback
I am trying to implement FoC for a BLDC motor. I have a dedicated control board(STM32H7) that receives current and angle feedback, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to measure the speed from the angle feedback. My initial was to use a timer that sets off at a regular interval, say 5ms, and capture the change in angle. Then, convert that to speed. However, I'm not sure if this is the most practical way of calculating speed.
What is the most practical way to measure speed in this case?
